# Why can you implement std::is_function in terms of std::is_const and std::is_reference?

Tags: c++, templates, std, sfinae, type-traits

How is the following an implementation for `std::is_function`?

```
template<class T>
struct is_function : std::integral_constant<
    bool,
    !std::is_const<const T>::value && !std::is_reference<T>::value
> {};
```

(from [CPP Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function))

Seems to me, an `int` would be a function under this definition. What am I missing?

Comment: Think about the `!is_const` part.

Comment: Why can't function types be const? Is this related to abominable types?

Comment: @jtbandes it's because functions are one of the few things in C++ that aren't objects.

Comment: I guess because in a sense it's always const

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Let's go over the conditions as they appear:
If `const T` isn't const (`const` doesn't really apply to function types since functions aren't objects), and `T` isn't a reference (`const` doesn't apply to references either for the same reason), it's a function type. `int` (or any other non-function-non-reference type) wouldn't fit in because `is_const<const int>::value` is `true`.

According to [C++17 Standard §11.3.5 Functions / section 7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#7): (Emphasis mine)

> The effect of a cv-qualifier-seq in a function declarator is not the
>   same as adding cv-qualification on top of the function type. In the
>   latter case, the cv-qualifiers are ignored. [ Note: **A function type
>   that has a cv-qualifier-seq is not a cv-qualified type; there are no
>   cv-qualified function types.** — end note ] [...]

Comment: Ah.... I was missing the "const" inside the is_const part of this. That makes sense.

Answer (score 61):

There are only two categories of types in the language that *cannot* have const-qualification: reference types, and function types. So, if `const T` fails to be a const-qualified type, it means `T` is either a function type or a reference type. If you can rule out reference types, then you are left with only function types.

Note that a function type that carries a cv-qualifier, such as `int(int) const`, is *not* a const-qualified type. It's an example of an "abominable function type", whose only real use is to compose or decompose pointer-to-member-function types. The type `int(int) const` cannot be obtained by adding const-qualification on top of `int(int)`. Rather, the `const` applies to the implied object parameter.

Comment: could you please provide an example of the use case for ```int(int) const``` ?